# percentage histogram with matplotlib, One input to the axis is a combination of two columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a data frame with a class value I am trying to predict. I am interested in label 1.
 I am trying to determine if turn plays a role for a given key value.
For a given key value of say 1 and a turn number of 1, what percentage of turns have a class value of 1?

For example for the given data

key=1,turn=1,8/11 have a class label 1
key=1,turn=2,5/6 have a class label 1

How can I plot a percentage histogram for this type of data?
I know a normal histogram using matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('PS')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist()
```

but what values I would use to get the percentage histogram?

Sample columns from the dataframe

key=[
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
]

turn=[
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4]

class=[0
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
0
1
0
1
1
0
1
1
0
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
0
0]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib Histogram Time vs. Percentage (NBA stats)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434709/matplotlib-histogram-time-vs-percentage-nba-stats)

Comment: I checked the above link, but I have a total of 3 columns to consider for the plot one in contrast to the above link with just 2 columns.

Comment: The problem is your question is not clear enough to provide you an answer, so you need to adapt the example with 2 to 3 columns - which is pretty easy. Unless the question is [edit]ed, I would still consider this to be a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe you start by explaining what you mean by percentage histogram. If I understand correctly this is exaclty what is shown in the answer to the linked question. If you think it isn't, describe the problem, why using the method of calculating different histograms and normalizing them does not help you. Also make sure to clearly state what the output should look like.

Comment: I reframe it as: For every key, there are some turns and hence key+turn forms a group. Within this group, we have some class labels for every row. For every such group in the data frame I want to plot how many rows have a value of 1.  Example key=1,turn=1,8/11 have a class label 1. key=1,turn=2,5/6 have a class label .  What is the best plot to show this percentage histogram. The linked question just uses numbers from a column of dataframe. I do not have any such column.

Comment: Sorry, it was by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the concepts from the linked question are apparently not what you need, an alternative would be to produce pie charts as shown below.

[image]

```
key=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ]
turn=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
clas=[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({"key":key, "turn":turn, "class":clas})
piv = pd.pivot_table(df, values="class", index="key", columns="turn")
print piv
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=2)
for i in range(2):
    axes[i,0].set_ylabel("key {}".format(i+1))
    for j in range(4):
        pie = axes[i,j].pie([piv.values[i,j],1.-piv.values[i,j]], autopct="%.1f%%")
        axes[i,j].set_aspect("equal")
        axes[0,j].set_title("turn {}".format(j+1))

plt.legend(pie[0],["class 1","class 0"], bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5), loc="right", 
                          bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)       
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. This would be interesting to look at for my data. But I have 100 keys with 6 turns each and hence I was thinking of some kind of histogram that gives me across all keys, and turns. Is it possible to have one plot where I can combine all the keys and then show the percentage of each class in a turn?

Comment: Everything is possible. However since you oppose the way the linked question tackles the issue and also ignore most of my comments, which were meant to help you clarify your question, I fear there is not much I can do for you. As a last resort, you may of course draw the kind of plot and include an image, instead of describing what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that. I really appreciate your help, but I am just a novice with matplotlib and hence could not explain it well. I want a plot similar to the linked question where it clearly shows the effect of a variable on the class attribute. If I consider each row as a sentence and each turn made up of a number of sentences then what percentage of sentences within a turn get a class label of 1, across the dataset.